# data type mismatch in criteria expression: Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet, I am inserting values in the excel using an insert query as shown below

```
insert into [Customer_information$](Customer_ID, First_Name, Last_Name,Customer_Name,Title, Company, Division,Address_1, Address_2, City, State,Zip_Code, Office_No_, Mobile_No,Email)values ('2','bhanu','ff','bhanu ff',Null,'ff',Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,'a@gmailc.com')
```

The problem is, if for the first row I execute the above query, it will insert values however if I run this query again replacing any 'Null' with some value , it results in Data type mismatch error.
I tryied IMEX = 1 in connection string,
I tried passing blank string and space instead of null in the query but no results

I am using ADODB connection

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I deleted the sheet and insert with same name, it worked. Can anyone help why it started working.

Answer (score 0):

The word "NULL" is not equal to the value Null and fields such as Zip_Code are probably expecting a numeric value and not character values.

Without seeing your particular workbook, this is only a guess.

To pass Null values try:

```
values ('2','bhanu','ff','bhanu ff',,'ff',,,,,,,,,'a@gmailc.com')
```